# Android Q foregroundServiceType attribute

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-10.0

Why need foregroundServiceType attribute in Android Q except for location? In case a service is used for location access, we need to set it. But, what about other types?
https://developer.android.com/preview/features#fg-service-types
Do we really need to set them? And if not, will there be some problems or exceptions?

Comment: The `mediaProjection` one definitely is needed if you intend to use the media projection APIs. You will get an exception without it.

Comment: No, the question is do we really need to use this attribute in cases except for location access. I mean, if we don't set it when we use foreground service for calls for example

Comment: "the question is do we really need to use this attribute in cases except for location access" -- and my comment is that you need to use `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"` if you intend to use the media projection APIs from your foreground service. I do not know if the other service types are enforced or not, which is why I did not post an answer, merely a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able access some APIs from the service in Android Q.
Take a look at Javadoc in [Android sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.java)